# Syntax error in a for loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, syntax-error

this is my first question here but I've visited this site many times to find answers.
I'm facing what seems to be a really dumb problem.
I'm trying to create a '2d' list in python but a syntax error is teasing me.
Here is my code:

```
def gen2darr(row, column):  # generates an array
    for in range row:
        arr.append([])  # create the lines
    for i in range row:
        for in range column:
            arr[i].append(float(int(row*column*random)))   
            # fills the array, float(int( because I want floats that 'are ints', 
            # ex: 2.0 or 152.0
```

and here is what I get:

```
    for in range row:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I've tried putting a value in the for loop in this way:

```
    for j in range row:
```

but I then get this:

```
    for j in range row:
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Can someone help me with this?
For me syntax error means I'm likely missing a bracket or a coma somewhere but I cannot find it.

Comment: Do you expect this 2D list to get filled with random numbers? It won't. But you need to read the docs on the `random` module to understand why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use a range, then you need to **call** the  function:

```
for j in range(row):
```

`range` is not part of the Python syntax, it is just another [built-in object type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Somehow, I though I could not use the brackets

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is:

```
for j in range(row):
```

`range` is a function taking an argument. And you have to specify which variable you will use to iterate (`j`)

Answer (score 1):

The range function have following syntax: range(limit 1, limit 2), you pass like argument a size of array you want.